# How to access subcollection data within Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a music app, and I am trying to access a subcollection within my Firebase database that contains information about a certain music track (track data). When I console log my query of the collection within vs code the collection refuses to show up. Nothing is printed. Screenshot 1 shows there is clearly data within the collection.

[Firebase Database set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTZRC.jpg)

My code to fetch the data is as follows.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (auth.currentUser) {
    const fetchTracks = async () => {
      try {
        const tracksRef = collection(
          db,
          "musicNotes",
          auth.currentUser.uid,
          "trackData"
        );
                                       // create query

        const q = query(tracksRef);
                                         // execute query

        const querySnap = await getDocs(q);

        querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });

         console.log("test");

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchTracks();
  }
}, []);
```

```
  console.log(auth.currentUser.uid)
  produces : MEglsLRYjITYmbnl6ooGGhVo7R33
```

No error is thrown up just an empty console. I have console logged "test" after the querySnap to show it is being run. Am I missing something?

[Screenshot of console after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICPrZ.jpg)

Comment: Hi Frank, I have added this to the bottom of the post, I do believe it matches the correct path in the firebase database.

Comment: Appreciate the help Frank. Updating as such!

Comment:  cleaning up comments, so they're not distracting anyone.

Comment: I think the problem lies in how you are querying the firestore db. You have set no query in your query, and you are passing extra params to .collection() method, try to check this docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: A little update -  I found that the part of the code that is making it not work is the auth.currentUser.uid . For some reason Firestore is not allowing me to access the Document when it is the same name as the ID generated by Firebase (musicNotes/auth.currentUser.uid/trackdata/...). Strange bug? If I however change the name to lets say (musicNotes/123/trackdata/..) and then hardcode collection(
          db,
          "musicNotes",
          123,
          "trackData"
        ); Then the code allows me to access the collection. I may make a new post with this new problem.